# Problem with phploy deployment on windows

Tags: git, deployment

I'm deploying using PHPloy on windows.
I install phploy in `C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\PHPloy and` define path in System variable "path".

Also I install phploy.in in my project directory `F:\xampp\htdocs\Project`.
But when I run phploy in git it returns error.

> phploy
>   bash: phploy: command not found

phploy in git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check where phploy.exe is actually installed.

Through [composer](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy#install), for instance, that would be in $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin, which by default is `%USERPROFILE%\.composer\vendor\bin`, as mentioned in [`banago/PHPloy` issue 98](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy/issues/98#issuecomment-89481760).

- find where `phploy.exe` is (since a `git bash` would not be able to run a `phploy.bat`)
- add it to your `%PATH%` before launching your `git bash` session.

Comment: Hello VonC
I have installed C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\PHPloy and also defined path in System variable "path".
But still im getting error.

Comment: Is `phploy.exe` in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\PHPloy` or in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\PHPloy\bin`

Comment: Its phploy not phploy.exe. and its in C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\PHPloy\bin.

Comment: @KamleshDjKammu Is phploy executable?